# I can't change title of navigationitem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, title, uinavigationitem

I need to learn how I can change title of navigation controller during the each implementation 
in my main screen (Navigation controller view) I have the name of the city(NAV Title) and my second view(table view) I have the list of cities and when I select another city in table I want it to be title of nav and return previous view (Nav View)

ex: title -->New york

When I select another city like Boston title need to be Boston

```
 title--->Boston
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.title = @"Boston";` in `viewDidAppear:animated:`

-- edit

actually you'd rather need to implement a protocol in your cities view controller to allow the main view controller to be notified about the city being selected. Read about the delegation pattern, there's plenty of answers on that matter here.

Comment: You should not wait until viewDidAppear or the title will appear after any push animations have finished. You want the title to be visible during the animation, don't you?

Comment: @MaciejSwic though this might be true, the question was not about the best practices of displaying content. If you read it more carefully instead of just randomly dropping irrelevant comments, you'll understand that it's not about simply changing the title of navigation bar, but about doing so via delegation pattern, read the -- edit part.

Comment: In that case, what does viewDidAppear have to do with anything? If you implement a delegate pattern, you set the title via the delegate method, not via viewDidAppear.